# What are the differences of editing UTS_RELEASE and EXTRAVERSION?

Tags: linux-kernel, make, version

`UTS_RELEASE` is in `include/generated/utsrelease.h`

`EXTRAVERSION` is in `makefile`

For example my kernel has `UTS_RELEASE "4.4.30-7+"` and the `EXTRAVERSION` contains `-7+`

Both are affecting the result of `uname -r` when built.

What are the differences between the two? Would they conflict each other if only one is edited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UTS_RELEASE` includes `EXTRAVERSION`. If you change `EXTRAVERSION`, `UTS_RELEASE` will be updated to reflect that. If you change `UTS_RELEASE` in `include/generated/utsrelease.h`, the file is liable to be rewritten the next time you build the kernel, which would lose your change. So don't touch `UTS_RELEASE`, edit `EXTRAVERSION` if you have to.

The kernel supports a local version too, which is defined in the kernel configuration and is designed to be changed in local builds. It is appended to the kernel release. You should probably use that!

Comment: So, if I only edit `UTS_RELEASE`, say from`4.4.30-7+` to `4.4.30-Custom+` and then build the kernel would `uname -r` result rolled back to `4.4.30-7+` ?

Comment: And I'm under the impression that `EXTRAVERSION` is the same as `local version`. Are they different?

Comment: Yes, you'd end up with "4.4.30-7+". `EXTRAVERSION` and the local version are different, and the kernel release contains both if they're defined. `EXTRAVERSION` isn't really user-modifiable (although it won't break if you do change it), it's intended for things like `-rc1`. You should really use the local version for your custom suffix.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment actually answered my [other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334453/why-uts-release-and-uts-sysname-are-located-in-different-files?rq=1) too. :)