# Getting kernel source code (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I want to try my hand at writing a linux driver. I am trying to set up my environment. My current kernel:

```
$ uname -r
4.10.0-37-generic
```

I then download the source code:

```
$ apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done 
Picking 'linux' as source package instead of 'linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic'
...
```

I go to compile and modprobe my driver, it fails. Looking in dmesg, it shows:

```
version magic '4.10.17 SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.10.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload '
```

At this point, I'm confused. I go back to the source tree I downloaded, and when I run

```
$ make kernelversion
4.10.17
```

Ok, try two.
Download kernel 4.10.17 and install it.

```
$ uname -r
4.10.17-041017-generic
```

Still error:

```
version magic '4.10.17 SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.10.17-041017-generic SMP mod_unload
```

So maybe someone can help: what is the best and correct way for me to get a working kernel and matching source on ubuntu (well, xubuntu, but I don't think it should matter)? Do I need to get the code from kernel.org and build it from scratch? I kinda want to match the shipping Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: The `linux-source-VERSION` where VERSION is 4.10.17 in your case is probably the package you want to install.

Comment: If you want to compile the packages, you need use `debuild`.

Comment: @ivan seems like linux-source defaults to linux-source-4.10.17 but it doesn't match 4.10.17-041017-generic

Comment: I pulled the code from kernel.org and I'm going to try to match it that way.  @sebasth I didn't see any mention of debuild on any of the guides at ubuntu.com. I'd need a little more help, though for now I'm compiling the kernel.org code.

Comment: On the comment to @ivanivan above, what I meant is that the source code comes down correctly (4.10.17) but doesn't match the version in the kernel package which has the extra -xxxx-generic.

Comment: @WillIAm - those numbers are set at either config time or compile time, forget which.  You may try grabbing your config from the /boot directory, run a `make oldconfig` and then try to apply your patch/compile your module

Comment: In your question you use `apt-get source` to get the sources. If you use vanilla kernel from *kernel.org*, you should edit your question to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks, sebath. I wasn't using the vanilla kernel, I'm trying to use it now since I couldn't reconcile the issue in the question. The question of how to get the exact matching source code for a shipping Ubuntu kernel still stands.

Comment: in your `utsrelease.h` file , append the sign `+` in the end of your release version `UTS_RELEASE xx.x.x+

Comment: @GAD3R, [no, don’t do that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336181/86440).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of approaches...

1. If you’re trying to build an external module (including one you’re developing), you only need the kernel headers:

   ```
   apt install linux-header-$(uname -r)
   ```

   This will provide the necessary files so that the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/{build,source}` symlinks point to something meaningful. Then you can build a module in another directory by running

   ```
   make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build SUBDIRS="/path/to/your/module" modules
   ```

   This will ensure that the module is built for the kernel you’re running.
2. If you want to base your development on the Ubuntu kernel, use the appropriate `linux-source` package; for your release of Ubuntu, that’s currently [`linux-source-4.10.0`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+source/linux):

   ```
   apt install linux-source-4.10.0
   cd /usr/src
   tar xf linux-source-4.10.0.tar.bz2
   ```

   This will include the Ubuntu kernel patches, allowing you to build a kernel with the same features as your current kernel. Note however the caveat from the package description:

   > This package is mainly meant for other packages to use, in order to build
   >   custom flavours.
   >
   > If you wish to use this package to create a custom Linux kernel, then it
   >   is suggested that you investigate the package kernel-package, which has
   >   been designed to ease the task of creating kernel image packages.
   >
   > If you are simply trying to build third-party modules for your kernel,
   >   you do not want this package. Install the appropriate linux-headers
   >   package instead.
3. If you want to base your development on the upstream kernel (which is what I’d recommend), you should clone [Linus’ tree](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/) and work there. To test your module, you’ll need to either build a full upstream kernel, or build your module using the approach given in point 1 above.

In any case it’s not a good idea to use the [linux](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux) source package itself (as obtained using `apt-get source`), since that’s really designed for building all the kernels used in Ubuntu. If you blindly `debuild` using that source package, you’ll wait for many hours before the build finishes... (There are circumstances where this *is* appropriate, and the Ubuntu kernel documentation will explain what to do; but this is very likely not one of them.)

Comment: I installed 'linux-source-4.10.0' and get the same error - 'version magic '4.10.17 SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.10.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload'. If you check Makefile in 4.10.0-37-generic - its configured that version is '4.10.17'